# How to disable iNotes for a single mail file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Should be simple, but IBM doesn't make it easy...

How do I NOT use iNotes when accessing a mail file over HTTP.

I would like to access a custom view and form to my mail file, but I cannot seem to bypass iNotes.  The server always gives me an iNotes page instead of my form.

If I use an old mail file template, it will work, but somewhere in the newer mail templates there is a 'switch' that says use iNotes.

Obviously I still want HTTP, just not iNotes on this one mail file -- I do not want to use an old email template.  Where is the 'switch?'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What URL are you sending? What changes have you made to the mail file design?

Comment: The URL is //hostname/mail/mailfile.nsf/0/ba4b8dbec6ae52908625740500014d92?OpenDocument .  I have tried several design changes but none have changed anything.  Currently I am using an old Memo form from another db that does not bring up iNotes, but it hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Torsten for 2 options.

I may as well describe the solution in detail:

In **Domino Designer**, open the **Icon** in the **Resources** folder for the database.

Click on the **Properties** tab, select **Document IDs**, and copy down the **Note ID** -- in my case the value was `0000011E`.

Run the following agent in LotusScript:

```
Sub Initialize
   Dim session As New NotesSession
   Dim db As NotesDatabase
   Dim iconDoc As NotesDocument

   Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
   'NoteID of icon document from icon properties
   Set iconDoc = db.GetDocumentById("11E")

   'Delete the field $FormsTemplateFile
   Call iconDoc.RemoveItem("$FormsTemplateFile")

   Call iconDoc.Save(True, True)

End Sub
```

This gets the icon design doc by NoteID from which you can modify any of the fields 'hiding' there.  Removing $FormsTemplateFile disconnects the mail file from using iNotes.  Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You can force the "classic" ui by adding an URL parameter:

`hxxp://yourserver.yourdomain.com/mail/mailfile.nsf?OpenDatabase&ui=webmail`

Same works for opening a view:

`hxxp://yourserver.yourdomain.com/mail/mailfile.nsf/YourView?OpenView&ui=webmail`

If you want to completely disable iNotes for a mailfile without URL hacking, then you can delete the "link" to the corresponding FormsX.nsf- File. This link is stored in the database icon. The icon document contains an item called `$FormsTemplateFile`. 
This "context" has been reveiled, when something went wrong with the german templates in R9 that still pointed to Forms85.nsf. Check [this link at IBM](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=1C92CE5A1537E08985257B590043D8C0) for details. The code in that link can also be used to solve your problem by removing the "linking" item:

```vb
Dim sess As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim item As NotesItem
Dim newFF As String
Dim itemFF As NotesItem

Set db = sess.CurrentDatabase
Dim session As New NotesSession

Dim n As String
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
n = "FFFF0010"
Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID (n)

' original code from post
'Set itemFF = doc.GetFirstItem("$FormsTemplateFile")
'newFF = Inputbox("Enter new Forms File name", "Change Forms File", itemFF.values(0))
'Set item = doc.ReplaceItemValue("$FormsTemplateFile", newFF)

'new line to fix problem
Call doc.RemoveItem( "$FormsTemplateFile" )
Call doc.save(True,True)
```

This works, because in every database the Icon has the same fix noteid.

Comment: Thank you, that does override iNotes.  But removing the ui=webmail parameter from the URL would still allow viewing the mail doc with the iNotes form and all its buttons/features (web crawlers try many forms of the URL).  Is there a way to indicate in the design somewhere that this is a mail file that is NOT to be connected to iNotes?

Comment: I know, that in the database- icon there is a link to the used FormsX.nsf in the item "$FormsTemplateFile". If you programmatically remove the "$FormsTemplateFile"- Item from the database- icon that might stop the usage of iNotes...

Comment: Holy cow, interesting place to hide things!  Torsten, if you update your answer, I can mark it as the solution.  Thanks!